# How to remove custom taxonomy-base from URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help me in wordpress.

I want to remove custom texnonomy base from URL in wordpress

```
http://domainname/travel-category/beaches
to 
http://domainname/beaches
```

where "travel-category" is custom register taxonomy base and "beaches" is category

MY CODE IS :

```
register_taxonomy(
                'travel-category', //taxonomy base
                'destination', // custom post type
                 ...
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

DO one thing add the following code for the `rewrite` argument for `register_taxonomy` function:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug'  => '/',  'with_front' => FALSE ),
```

Hope this works and if not try refreshing the permalink page.

Comment: This breaks page/post urls.

Comment: This fixes the taxonomy url but 404s every other page on the site.

Comment: This works for me, thanks.Context: building website with 2 CPTs (with similar rewrite array in their register_post_type() args array. Aim: have URLs like /<term>/<CPT1 post name> and /<term>/<CPT2 post name> (and be careful to never have CPT1 and CPT2 posts name conflict.